# URL forwarding with two arguments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, web, lamp

This is my current .htaccess

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ index.php?u=$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It turns **www.example.com** into **example.com** AND interprets **example.com/username** AS **example.com/index.php?u=username**

Now I want to pass a second argument like **example.com/index.php?u=username&e=email** and still keep the format **example.com/arg1&arg2**. How do I do that in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to move the redirect *before* your routing rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then, you want to check the 2 argument route:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?u=$1&e=$2 [L,QSA]
```

(this assumes a URL that looks like: `http://example.com/username/emailaddress`, but if you really want the `&` to separate them, use this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)&([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?u=$1&e=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And this assumes a URL that looks like: `http://example.com/username&emailaddress`

Now your original rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ /index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works when I pass both arguments. How to make it universal for cases when I pass only one arg?

Comment: @LeonardoDaVintik If it works according to your question, you should consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the answer first.

Comment: @LeonardoDaVintik What do you mean by "universal for cases when I pass only one arg"? The rules that you originally had takes care of the 1 argument case. The ones above that, the 2 argument requests, and the top is the redirect.